# Running the java class in the terminal failing

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I tried to run my java class generated using netbeans 10.0 in terminal as below:

```
 ~/Desktop/JavaLesson5/build/classes/javalesson5$ java javalesson5.JavaLesson5
```

but I keep getting the error below:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javalesson5.JavaLesson5
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javalesson5.JavaLesson5
```

My java code is as below:

```
package javalesson5;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaLesson5{

    public static double myPI = 3.14159; //Class variable

    public static int addThem(int a, int b){
      double smallPI = 3.140;//Local variable
      System.out.println("Local "+myPI);

      int c = a + b;
      return c;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(addThem(1,2));
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are running your program within pacakge.so just write "java JavaLesson5".

Comment: It returns the same error

Comment: Is class file of that program generated?just cross check.

Comment: Yeah, its in the same directory

Comment: First compile program and then try to run at same package.

Comment: @Sanjay nope, that doesn't work. In theory Java could try to work out the classpath based on (a) the current directory and (b) the package of the main class. But it would only be useful in a small number of cases and probably not worth the effort of explaining how it works.

Comment: Oh.Now I understand.problem is of class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
java -cp ~/Desktop/JavaLesson5/build/classes javalesson5.JavaLesson5
```

You use `classes` as the classpath because you've specified `javalesson5` as part of the classname. For each directory in the classpath (just one in this example) Java will look for a directory called `javalesson5` and then look for the `JavaLesson5` class in that directory.

Comment: I had earlier tried it in its folder but it had still failed. Does that mean that the approach of      java javalesson5.JavaLesson5    is totally wrong and should not be used?

Comment: You always have to set the classpath either by specifying `-cp` or setting the environment variable `CLASSPATH`. If you set `CLASSPATH` to `~/Desktop/JavaLesson5/build/classes` then you can run `java javalesson5.JavaLesson5` without specifying `-cp`.

Comment: I now understand the whole concept. Thank you